# Wagtail streamfield inside a snippet / setting not working as expected

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield, wagtail-snippet

Edit: Seems like I can't add images :(, added links to imgur instead.

---

I'm trying to implement settings in order to enter social media accounts.

```
@register_setting
class SocialMediaSettings(BaseGenericSetting):
    discord_url = models.URLField(
        help_text="Link used."
    )
    discord_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        help_text="Name to be displayed."
    )
    gitlab_url = models.URLField(
        help_text="Link used."
    )
    gitlab_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        help_text="Name to be displayed."
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("discord_url"),
        FieldPanel("discord_name"),
        FieldPanel("gitlab_url"),
        FieldPanel("gitlab_name")
    ]
```

Which works totally fine, but as it feels like a super bad idea to do it this way, I wanted to use a streamfield like this:

```
@register_setting
class SocialMediaSettings(BaseGenericSetting):
    body = StreamField([
        ("social_account", blocks.SocialBlock()),
    ], null=True, blank=True, use_json_field=True)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("body")
    ]

class SocialBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    name = blocks.CharBlock(
        max_length=100,
        help_text="Name used for tooltips."
    )
    url = blocks.URLBlock(
        help_text="URL"
    )
```

[Image of wagtail admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AhRr.png)  (image)

This way it shows up partly. In the admin panel I can only enter the name, not the url. And saving doesn't work eighter (saving will reset what I entered in the admin panel).

Adding the SocialBlock to a normal page works as expected:
[SocialBlock working in another Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCF9w.png)  (image)

Which is why I ran out of ideas. Are streamfields not supported in snippets / settings? (the above exapmles are done with @register_setting but I tried @register_snippet with the same result.)

Any idea how I could get this up and running?

Wagtail 4.0
Django 4.1

Answer (score 0):

Well, wagtail itself just showed me the solution :x

It was a bug in Wagtail 4.0, which is solved in 4.0.1
[Release Notes Wagtail 4.0.1](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/v4.0.1/releases/4.0.1.html)